# error: no matching function for call to'std::_Rb_tree_iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary

I get this error when I compile my code, and I don't understand why. I have used the same iteration in other methods and it works.

```
src/Stats/Stats.cpp:24:53: error: no matching function for call to'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, Onglet> >::_Rb_tree_iterator(std::map<int, Onglet>::const_iterator)'
```

The class Stats has as an attribut `std::map <int , Onglet >` stat.

And here's my code:

```
#include "Stats.hpp"
#include "./Application.hpp"
#include "./Utility/Utility.hpp"

//Constructeur:
Stats::Stats()
{}

//Destructeur:
Stats::~Stats()
{}

/*Dessin*/
void Stats::drawOn(sf::RenderTarget& target) const
{
    for(std::map<int,Onglet>::iterator i(stat.begin()); i != stat.end() ; ++i)
    {  
        int id = (i->first);
        if(id == identifiantActif)
        {
            (i->second).graphe->drawOn(target);
        }
    }
}


void Stats::setActive(int id)
{
    identifiantActif = id;
}

void Stats::reset()
{
    for(std::map<int,Onglet>::iterator i(stat.begin()); i != stat.end() ;  ++i)
    {
        (i->second).graphe->reset();    
    }   
}

void Stats::addGraph(int id,std::string const& title, 
                  std::vector<std::string> const& series, 
                   double min, double max, Vec2d const& size)
{

    for(std::map<int,Onglet>::iterator i(stat.begin()); i != stat.end() ; ++i)
    {
        setActive(id);
        stat[id].graphe.reset(new Graph(series,size,min,max));  
    }
}
```

Comment: not totally clear whats going on without more info but it looks like you need to use a `const_iterator` in `drawOn` because it is a const function.

Comment: You should use `std::map<int,Onglet>::const_iterator` in a member function marked const

Comment: @DieterLücking That's an answer not a comment.

Comment: yeah thank you that was the error :) i had to use a const_iterator :))

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::map<int,Onglet>::const_iterator` in a member function marked const –